# Multiple setState queues up and causes everything to feel slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS menu component with 4 buttons which triggers the right-hand side of my page and a bunch of filters to reload on click.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="menu">
            {
                this.state.items.map(function(menuNode) {
                    return (
                        <MenuItem item={menuNode} onClick={this.handleClick} key={menuNode.name} />
                    );
                }, this)
            }
        </div>
    );
},
handleClick: function(selected) {
    this.state.items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.selected = false;
    });
    selected.selected = true;
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    });

    resetReact.BoxStructure(selected);
    resetReact.Filter(selected);
}
```

`resetReact.BoxStructure()` and `resetReact.Filter()` triggers a `setProps()`/`setState()` with new content in my page (BoxStructure) and filter components.

They are set in `componentDidMount` on each of those components like so:

```
var BoxStructure = React.createClass({

    ...

    componentDidMount: function() {
        if(this.props.callback)
            this.props.callback();

        resetReact.BoxStructure = function(selected) {
            this.state.boxes = selected.content;
            this.setProps({
                color: selected.color,
                callback: selected.callback,
                key: selected.name
            });
        }.bind(this);
}
});
```

This works, but the menu feels really slow and it's like it's waiting for the entire page to load before it changes selected menu item. BoxStructure is taking several seconds to load, which is fine and expected, but I don't want the menu to wait for that before it changes the selected item. From a user perspective it feels like nothing happened when I clicked the button.

This can be solved by adding `setTimeout` 1ms:

```
handleClick: function(selected) {
    this.state.items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.selected = false;
    });
    selected.selected = true;
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        resetReact.BoxStructure(selected);
        resetReact.Filter(selected);
    }, 1);
}
```

Now the menu changes instantly and then the page may take as long as it likes to render, just the way I want it to, but the question is why and am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I think `setTimeout` is forcing reloading to be asynchronous, but I get the feeling it's not the right way to achieve what I want and maybe ReactJS have a better way built in somewhere.

Comment: What does the `resetReact.BoxStructure` and `.Filter` do? What's happening is that you're offloading the animation until the next tick in the event loop. Which is why you feel that it's faster. Most likely the bug is in either of those functions.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more detailed explanation of what the resetReact functions do. They are basically just telling BoxStructure and Filter to update with new content.

Comment: Have you profiled the JavaScript? There's apparently a lot more happening than you've provided here. It shouldn't take seconds to render.

Comment: There is a lot more going on (represented by `...` above), but I'm fine with it taking a few seconds since it's actually doing tons of things with graphs and data. The problem I'm having is that the menu doesn't update until BoxStructure is done, so the selected menu option doesn't change to the current one until everything is loaded. I wan't to update the menu instantly as I press the button to indicate that the user actually pressed it, then the page on the right hand side of the menu can load for as long as it likes (it has a spinning hourglass and is ment to be working for a while).

Comment: I should add that I'm doing some DOM manipulations after render, even though that is not recommended. I do this because I require some information about the rendered elements dimensions and locations for third party libraries. This is why I don't have all my calculations and data processing done before I tell React to re-render the BoxStructure, which would be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

You should work on making your `BoxStructure` and `Filter` code more efficient. You may want to profile them, print milliseconds timestamps, and do other such things.

If you know that those calls are going to be slow, and you want to give your user feedback about what's happening, you may want to delay those heavy calls until the previous state update is completed ***and rendered***.

The way to do that is by using the callback to setState:

```
handleClick: function(selected) {
    ...
    this.setState({
        items: ...
    }, function() {
        resetReact.BoxStructure(selected);
        resetReact.Filter(selected);
    });
}
```

From the docs:

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be executed once setState is completed ***and the component is re-rendered***.

Also from the docs:

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

You're skirting a fine line by mutating this.state and then feeding it back to setState(). Don't do that.

As an alternative, instead of storing a `selected` flag in each item, you can store a single `selectedItem` index in your state (an integer between 0 and `items.length` - 1) so you only have to update that single variable.

Moreover, why are your menu items in the state to begin with? Is the user allowed to change them? If the answer is no, then you should put them in props or class constants.